# Visual Studio unpushed git commits indicator limited to 99 (indicates 99*)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017

I cannot seem to unlock the *Unpushed Commits* indicator to quickly view how many commits I have made. This is however not necessary when you regularly push, though I like to keep some projects locally.

Here is an example:

[image]

The same applies for the indicator next to it, which is the *change indicator*.
I looked in the git settings, though no such option seems to exist.

Currently using *Visual Studio 2017RC*, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue as yours in my VS2017 RC, but if you put the mouse on it, it would share the correct value:

[image]

My suggestion is that you'd better edit your project files together, and then commit them with few times. Or just put the mouse on the "99*", and view the real items.

Of course, since it is the RC version, I also help you submitted a feedback to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15796/visual-studio-unpushed-git-commits-indicator-limit.html

You could vote and add your comment there:)

Comment: Did you seriously make a 100 commits to test it?